# Latex problem with eps figures generated with Matlab

Tags: pdftex, eps, matlab, dvi, epstopdf

I have generated eps figures for my article which encountered problem with Latex. When I compile it with Latex --> dvi , The figure on the left side does not appear properly as can be seen in the picture. When I use pdflatex with     "\usepackage{epstopdf}" , it is ok.  I need eps figures because the Journal does no accept pdf or other formats. Thanks in advance.

I have found that this problem occurs when there are two figures parallel to each other, one on the left column and one on the right column (like Fig.3 and Fig.4 in my case). When i remove Fig.4, then everything is ok with Fig.3

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you show us an Minimal Working Example?

Comment: I have a two column article, on the left column, the eps encounter this problem. Half of the figure even does not appear